# How to pass values in WordPress from JS from page to page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have two JS widgets on my WordPress site and I need to pass parameters from one widget to another. I know it is can be done with URL parameters.
Any other suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a pure javascript solution, there area a few options:

- Add the parameters to the URL queryString from page #1 and then read them form page #2 (using document.location.href).
- Use cookies
- Use localStorage (if available):

LocalStorage example:

In page #1, save your data:

```
if (window.localStorage) {
   localStorage.setItem("myVar", "value");
}
```

In page #2 you can get the myVar value:

```
if (window.localStorage) {
   var myValue = localStorage.getItem("myVar");
   /* do your stuff */
}
```